How to get real time token data to show on chart?
This is not a question realted to code but, more of a knowledge.
I am trying to wrap my head around it but, cannot really understand how all these CEX like Binance, Coinbase, Bybit etc and DEX, Uniswap, Jup etc get the information about token prices to show on the chart. I have been trying to find a source but, cannot really find an authentic source that would give me real-time information about token prices. I am trying to integrate drift in my Solana dapp and drift uses their own contracts for spot and perp trading. So, in that case, would I need to get the data about tokens from drift or can I use any other source?
In the following drift site,  https://app.drift.trade/ If you look into the chart and click on three horiziatal dots in Change symbol field at the top left corner of the chart, the listed exchange here is drift. Does that mean that the price information for that specific pair in this case ETH-PERP can only be found in drift? Can I use any other source? I need real-time price information to show on chart.

